# SQL average by customer per month

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, nested

The table 'transactions' is a list of all transactions with `date`, `customerID`, cost per unit (`price`) and `quantity`.

I need a report that groups transactions into months and gives a count, the total income and the average income per customer.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to insert `group by customerID` into this select statement:

```
SELECT extract(month FROM date) month,
       count(*) purchases,
       SUM(price*quantity) income,
       AVG(SUM(price*quantity)) <-- this needs to be grouped by customerID aswell as month
FROM
    transactions
WHERE
    date BETWEEN i2 AND i3
GROUP BY extract(month FROM date);
```

The closest I can get is something like:

```
SELECT extract(month FROM date) month,
       count(*) purchases,
       SUM(price*quantity) income,
       ( SELECT AVG(SUM(price*quantity))
         FROM transactions
         GROUP BY customerID, extract(month FROM date) )
FROM
    transactions t
WHERE
    date BETWEEN i2 AND i3
GROUP BY extract(month FROM date);
```

But that approach stops making sense after I think about it for a minute since the nested `select` would return multiple rows. And if I add a `where` clause and remove the `group by date` in the second select:

```
(SELECT AVG(SUM(price*quantity))
 FROM transactions
 GROUP BY customerID
 where extract(month FROM date) = month)
```

Then it would return... I'm not sure what, but it would be wrong.

It's an oracle database by the way (10g I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using arithmetic . . . divide the total by the number of customers:

```
SELECT extract(month FROM date) month,
       count(*) purchases,
       SUM(price*quantity) income,
       sum(price*quantity) / count(distinct customerId)
FROM
    transactions
WHERE
    date BETWEEN i2 AND i3
GROUP BY extract(month FROM date);
```

Comment: ...I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks.